# Gridview is clearing while clicking the nextpage

Tags: gridview

I have one gridview and it has pagination .if I fill something into grid then when I click second page then I go back to previous page I filled values is clearing.any solution for this issue .I am using data grid in asp.net c # . Thanks you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I am using asp.net , I have one gridview to show some records  from DB. And user can also enter some values to grid . My problem is  after binding the grid when I click pagination of grid (to second page ) then I go back to previous field user entered value is clearing.  How to stop this issue .

Comment: Hi pduersteler ,could you plz answer this question?

Comment: As stated, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and maybe check out how questions with answers and a lot of upvotes are formatted and written in order to update your question. If you don't put much effort in asking a question, you most likely won't get much effort from others to write an answer.